# Cookie Won't Delete

Tags: php, cookies

So I have this code on my index.php:

```
<?php if(isset($_POST['cookie'])) { setcookie("RememberMe", "Yes", time()+1209600);  } ?>
```

If the user has checked the remember me box then it will set a cookie with the name RememberMe for 2 weeks. This part works fine.

Now the issue I'm having is deleting this cookie when they press logout.

On pressing logout, they get redirected to logout.php which has the following code:

```
<?php include_once('config.php');
include_once('functions.php');

unset($_COOKIE['RememberMe']);
setcookie("RememberMe", "", time()-3600);
$_SESSION = array(); session_destroy(); 


?> 

<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;../index.php">
```

but for some strange reason that won't delete the cookie? Any ideas as to why?

Comment: Don't rely upon the meta redirection. It may be blocked on some browsers - unrelated to the concrete question.

Comment: Is your server in the right timezone? What happens when you use `time() - 36000`?

Comment: Doesn't change anything @WaleedKhan. It still remains.
Lion - What else is a better way to redirect them?

Comment: What URL is the cookie set at? Maybe it's set in a subdirectory causing it to be only available at a certain paths.

Comment: Having set an incorrect time zone on the server should not be relevant.

Comment: @Tenatious You should also use a header, Javascript, and a fall-back "click here if nothing happens" link.

Comment: @MichalM You were spot on. Just as you posted I realised it was being set in an incorrect place. Got it working now :)

Comment: Great to be of help. I actually managed to write an answer about this already, so feel free to accept.

Comment: for future referense - you should be looking at HTTP traffic first, headers sent & received, when debugging these. Not the PHP code. After you've found out what actually happens (vie the HTTP headers), it should be easy enough to adjust PHP code to do the right thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to check if the path the cookie is set at is correct. By default PHP sets the cookie path to the directory it's set in and it will not be available (nor possible to delete) from different locations.

Few more tips:

- there is no need to unset `$_COOKIE` and `$_SESSION`
- instead of redirecting using a meta tag redirect with HTTP headers:

  ```
  header('Location: /index.php'); // or whatever is the path you want to redirect to
  ```

Comment: Thanks. Will use the redirect method :)

Answer (score 0):

Not the cleanest but
Check the time zone is correct
Ensure you are nuking the correct cookie( case sensitive )
Failing all of they over writing the cookie will nuke it anyway
 So...

Setcookie('mycookie') // nukes the cookie with a blank entry

Comment: Why do you think the timezone on the server matters?

Comment: Bad past experiences I guess.  In hindsight should be irrelivent but I've had hosts with server times set to 1990's. So it's always best not to trust defaults unless checked :) ,

Comment: Even the server time doesn't matter. `setcookie` sends a `Set-Cookie` HTTP-Header field to the client, the client examines the `expires` attribute of that header field and uses this information to decide whether to send the cookie back to the server on the next request. So technically, there is no way to delete a cookie. You can only tell the client "I don't want you to send this cookie back to me", but the final descision is made by the client.

Answer (score 0):

Cookie cancelations can sometimes require the same time value as they were set.

```
setcookie("RememberMe", "", time()-1209600);
```

Answer (score 0):

remove this line

`unset($_COOKIE['RememberMe']);`